# How to compute angular velocity of fluid ring for passive control?

Tags: artificial-satellite, spacecraft, attitude, engineering

[image]

Excuse me, friends. In paper , for passive control with eq.4, how to compute beta?
beta is angular velocity of fluid in fluid. the satellite has initial angular velocity, but with filled fluid ring we want to damp it, until the velocity of satellite in space tends to zero!
Kind regards.

another link:[paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00707-008-0132-5#/page-1)

Comment: Looks much better! Our other users may ask you to refine the question further, but for now we at least know what calculations you are referring to.